# "An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command" while doing scroll down using Appium

Tags: java, android, appium

I have used following code to scroll down

```
WebElement elementToScroll = driver.findElement(By.id("id"));
scrollDown(elementToScroll, "Max Notifications Per Instance", driver);
((JavascriptExecutor ) driver).executeScript ("mobile: scroll", :direction => 'down');           
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
scrollObject.put("direction", "down");
scrollObject.put("element", ((RemoteWebElement) elementToScroll).getId());
scrollObject.put("text", elementToScroll.getText()); 
js.executeScript("mobile: scroll", scrollObject);
```

and in setup I have changed `WebDriver driver` into `driver = new RemoteWebDriver();` because to hookup my script with sauce lab

Everything is working properly but when I try to do scrolling its giving error

> An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)(..)

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: If it is not working using JavaScript whay don't you go for native Action API?    WebElement Slider = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='slider-range']/a[1]"));

     Actions moveSlider = new Actions(driver);
     Action action = moveSlider.dragAndDropBy(Slider, 30, 0).build();

    action.perform();

Comment: OR   Actions dragger = new Actions(driver);
WebElement draggablePartOfScrollbar = driver.findElement(By.xpath("**xpath of slider**"));
int numberOfPixelsToDragTheScrollbarDown = 5000;
dragger.moveToElement(draggablePartOfScrollbar).clickAndHold().moveByOffset(0,numberOfPixelsToDragTheScrollbarDown).release().perform();

Answer (score 2):

I have been getting the unknown server-side error while writing automation tests with Appium and it is usually due to an element on the page - like a date picker or autocomplete menu - getting in the way of the element you are trying to click.

Make sure your scroll object is visible and there is nothing overlaying it. You could always use a [fluent wait](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html) to give any other elements time to finish what they are doing and get out of the way.

Answer (score 1):

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("my-id"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element);
// actions.click();
actions.perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used same code to scroll just change element 'elementToScroll'. I have used element for which scrollable value is 'true'

Comment: Please edit your answer with updated working code for you. It will help someone :-)

Comment: @Swapnil I have used same code just change element for which scrollable is true